# Supply chain model

Tags: machine-learning-model

Looking to build a supply chain model.

This would include weather data, shipping data, supply and demand levels.

Ultimate goal is to predict price using such a model.

Any ideas on how to develop something like this, any sample code, any previous examples from GitHub?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supply chain modeling requires a good simulator.

You can use existing software like [anyLogistix](https://www.anylogistix.com/download-free-supply-chain-simulation-software/) but you might be limited if you want to use other features such as the weather or the stock markets.

That's why a good option is to use simulators like [supplychainpy](https://pypi.org/project/supplychainpy/) or [simpy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpy_intro/basic_concepts.html), together with machine learning algorithms such as Random Forest to connect multiple features together and make interesting simulations and predictions like [demand forecasting](https://github.com/xiaofanc/Demand-Forecasting-Models) or [network optimization](https://github.com/samirsaci/supply-chain-optimization).